# How to do impedance matching when when all 3 characteristic impedances differ?

Tags: impedance-matching, characteristic-impedance

[image]

If we have a circuit like this and we need to do impedance matching on smith chart. How would we go about doing it? I think you would have to first normalize with the Zo1 and go to the 1+jX circle and denormalize. Then normalize again wrt Zo and plot it again? I am not sure can someone please explain.

Comment: Given that the 10 ohm load cannot be impedance matched to the 50 ohm line that feeds it, what, more precisely, is your question?

Comment: Not with the given setup but lets say we have a load (100 +j100) and had to match it with different characteristic impedances of the line. But the characterisitc impedances of the line aren't equal, how would you do it? Usually we consider it to be uniform but what if its not?

Comment: Please stop and think. This is a Q and A site and not a regular forum. If your new question is that in your comment then please amend your question but, do it quickly because, once someone answers your original question, question changes are not tolerated very well.

Comment: Do you have an answer?

Comment: The T connection that you have shown, (apart from terminating a 50 ohm line with 10 ohms -- bad!) is not proper. You can split a 50 ohm line to into two 100 Ohm loads in parallel, but what you have is a 100 Ohm line split into two 50 ohm lines in parallel, which has an effective impedance of 25 ohms. Power coming in from the left will be reflected at the junction. Note that a T junction, unless one of the branches is a short unterminated stub has a definite upstream and downstream orientation that needs to be observed.

Answer (score 1):

Before giving a general answer to your question, let's review some theory.

Here is a properly split and terminated simple T-junction, splitting an upstream transmission line into two downstream lines.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzYCcF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that each of the downstream lines is properly terminated, and the parallel equivalent impedance of the two downstream lines' characteristic impedances is equal to the characteristic impedance of the upstream line.
In this case, 100 ohms in parallel with 100 ohms gives an equivalent of 50 ohms.

Note also that this simple T connection has a definite upstream and downstream and this orientation must be observed. If power flows in the wrong direction, there will be reflections at the junction. That is, this connection type cannot be used for 2-way communication. (An exception is if one of the "downstream lines" is actually just a short stub, and has no termination resistor.)

To see this, consider the impedance looking *into* a downstream port of the simple T-connection. In our example, this impedance is 50 ohms in parallel with 100 ohms or 33.3 ohms. But this does not match the 100 ohm impedance of the cable connected to that port. So, power (or signals) fed upstream into a downstream port will be (partially) reflected.

There are alternative ways of connecting transmissions lines, for example directional couplers that do not have this problem. However, there is a price to be paid. Typically, a resistor will be used in the device and power will be lost. In many applications, this power loss is not a problem for the overall system.

Returning to the simple T connector. We notice that *by itself*, the characteristic impedances of the down stream transmission lines cannot be the same as the characteristic impedances of the upstream transmission line. This is rather inconvenient, but can be fixed with the addition of a transformer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frdSuu.png)</sup>

A transformer of ratio (approximately) 1.414:1 will make the load impedance on the secondary side appear to be twice as large when "viewed" by the primary side. (\$1.414 \approx \sqrt{2}\$). 1.414 is somewhat of an odd-ball ratio to wind a small transformer, and in directional couplers, mentioned above, the added resistor makes using such an odd-ball ratio unnecessary. Typically, a ratio of 2:1 is used in directional couplers.

Theoretically, this same technique of adding a transformer to the upstream side of a simple T junction could be used to connect three transmission lines of any arbitrary (real) impedances together. First find the equivalent parallel impedance of the down stream lines characteristic impedances, divide that into characteristic impedance of the upstream line, take the square root, and that is the necessary transformer ratio. However, there is a caveat. The fraction of the power going to each downstream line will depend upon the ratio of the two downstream line impedances. The line with the lower impedance will "hog" most of the power. If that is what you want, or if it at least meets your specifications, you don't need to do any more.
However, if you want to distribute the power to the two downstream sides in some other ratio, you will need to do something different.

If you want to distribute the power to two downstream transmission lines according to some specific ratio, use **two** transformers, one on each of the downstream ports of the junction.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f17Ly8.png)</sup>

The tricky thing here is to find the appropriate transformer ratios. Suppose we want the 75 ohm downstream line to get 1/5th of the power and the 50 ohm downstream line to get 4/5ths? Well, we want the impedance seen by the upstream line to be 50 ohms, so the impedance of "seen" at the primary of the 50 ohm line needs to be 1/5th of 50 ohms, or 10 ohms. The impedance seen at the primary of the 75 ohm line needs to be 4/5 of 50 ohms or 40 ohms. (Note that the fraction of the power each line gets is the *reverse* of the impedance ratio -- the larger impedance gets less power)

So, we want one transformer to convert from 10 ohms to 50 ohms, and the other to convert from 40 ohms to 75 ohms. The transformer ratios will need to be \$\sqrt{1/5}=0.447\$ and \$\sqrt{40/75}=0.73\$. Now these again, are very odd-ball transformer ratios. One can wind one oneself, using approximate ratios. **Or**, if the frequency of the signals is known in advance, one can make "transformers" out of LC circuits -- that is LC impedance matching networks. (There are a number of calculators online that can help one choose the right network and the right inductor and capacitor values).

As mentioned earlier on, simple T junctions do not support signals being sent from a downstream line to an upstream line (except in the case of short stubs). The good news is that the impedance matching technique described above can still be used if you use directional couplers instead of simple T junctions. A directional coupler will already have a transformer (or a "transformer") in it so the ports (typically) will all have the same impedance (typically 50 ohms or 75 ohms). To connect a 75 ohm line to a 50 ohm directional coupler, just use a \$\sqrt(75/50)=1.225\$ ratio transformer, or an LC impedance matching network. The semi-bad news is that directional couplers (as far as I know) have fixed power sharing ratios. Typically 50:50, but some other ratios may be commercially available. Not terrible news.

One thing that I have not shown how to handle is complex impedances. Complex impedances were mentioned in one of the comments. Typically, data and video transmission lines are operated at frequencies where their characteristic impedance is almost wholly resistive. (Land line telephone lines are an exception.) Because the characteristic impedance of the line is primarily resistive, you should NOT load them with complex impedance loads. This will cause reflections. Instead, you should cancel out the reactance **at the load**, so the line sees a resistive load. Thus the transmission line junction, simple Tee or directional coupler, will not need to handle complex impedances.